# How Store key in TPM 1.2

Tags: c#, c++, windows, tpm

How to store the key in TPM v1.2 on windows.

I want to store the key generated by me in TPM.

I have found some functions from TBS TPM Based Services tbsip_Submit_Command() this is used to submit the commands, I have also found the commands which can be used to store 
1. TPM_NV_DefineSpace
2. TPM_NV_ReadValue
3. TPM_NV_WriteValue 
but I am not able to understand how to use it.
Can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the WMI TPM api. You can use CNG.
[NCryptOpenStorageProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ncrypt/nf-ncrypt-ncryptopenstorageprovider) with MS_PLATFORM_CRYPTO_PROVIDER.

Comment: Thanks I had looked in the NCryptOpenStorageProvider but bit confused in using this.And One more thing is It possible to access TPM storage without administrator rights.